# How do I expose a signal to DBUS in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dbus

I know quiet well how to create methods – however, I wish to expose some signals using Python so that severall programms can be called at once.

```
class Bildschirm(dbus.service.Object):
    DBUS_NAME = 'hm.retro.Retro'
    DBUS_OBJECT_PATH = '/hm/retro/Retro'
    DBUS_INTERFACE = 'hm.retro.Retro'

    def __init__(self, _Visio):
        self.Visio = _Visio
        self.bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName(self.DBUS_NAME, bus=self.bus)

        super().__init__(bus_name, self.DBUS_OBJECT_PATH)


    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_INTERFACE, in_signature='i')
    def delta(self, nr):
        weiter = self.Visio.akt_sender_nr
        weiter = (weiter+nr) % SENDER_AM
        self.Visio.akt_sender_nr = weiter
        self.Visio.update_sender_labels()

        self.Visio.screen.force_update()
        self.Visio.screen.draw_next_frame()

    @dbus.service.signal(DBUS_INTERFACE)
    def config_change_visio(self):
        self.Visio.load_config()
        self.Visio.update_sender_labels()
        self.Visio.update_preset_labels()

        self.Visio.screen.force_update()
        self.Visio.screen.draw_next_frame()
```

However, if I try to call the signal with dbus-send:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=hm.retro.Retro /hm/retro/Retro hm.retro.Retro.config_change_visio
```

I get an error message:

```
    Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 654, in _message_cb
    (candidate_method, parent_method) = _method_lookup(self, method_name, interface_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 246, in _method_lookup
    raise UnknownMethodException('%s is not a valid method of interface %s' % (method_name, dbus_interface))
dbus.exceptions.UnknownMethodException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Unknown method: config_change_visio is not a valid method of interface hm.retro.Retro
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `--print-reply` to `dbus-send`, you are implying that the message type you’re sending is a method call, as only method calls can have a reply. The `dbus-send` man page says:

```
   --print-reply
       Block for a reply to the message sent, and print any reply received in
       a human-readable form. It also means the message type (--type=) is
       method_call.
```

Remove the `--print-reply` argument from your `dbus-send` invocation, and add `--type=signal` and it should work.

---

Note that while it shouldn’t affect this bug, it’s more conventional for D-Bus signal names to be in CamelCase, not underscore_case. The [D-Bus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names-member) says:

> It is conventional for member names on D-Bus to consist of capitalized
>   words with no punctuation ("camel-case"). Method names should usually
>   be verbs, such as GetItems, and signal names should usually be a
>   description of an event, such as ItemsChanged.

So perhaps your signal should be called `VisioConfigChanged` instead. Similarly, perhaps your method should be called something like `AddDelta`.